# Quantlib HW 1f model calibration not fitting to market normal vol quotes

Tags: volatility, programming, quantlib, rates

I am using Quantlib python to calibrate HW 1f model parameters from normal swaption vols quoted in the market (following the code in the cookbook - I fit both the mean-reversion & vol to market quotes)

I see the HW 1f vol is an average of the market implied vol term structure (for given expiry  and different maturities for example) and fits very poorly to all the quotes.

What's a recommended approach/model to match the vol term structure observed from ATM swaption vols? Does Quantlib support any other advanced models?

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a time-dependent volatility function rather than a constant volatility, typically a piece-wise constant volatility function is used and can reproduce the swaption vols exactly (presuming you are calibrating on a vertical or diagonal).

I'm not sure there is an implementation of the piecewise constant vol HW in QuantLib, hopefully someone can correct if I'm wrong. You may need to extend the sigma function to be time-dependent.

Comment: Thanks. Is the piece-wise constant vol function constant across maturities (t_maturity) or is it constant for: t_maturity - t_expiry). Is there a paper with some implementation (any language) that you can refer? Thanks

Comment: Piecewise constant across maturities. Please see https://people.kth.se/~aaurell/Teaching/SF2975_HT17/calibration-hull-white.pdf

Comment: To complete @BrownianBread's answer, in QuantLib, you can use the GSR (Gaussian Short Rate) model which is the same thing as the one-factor Hull-White model, described here: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2246013. The piecewise-constant volatilities should be constant between consecutive expiries.